# Why did not highlight current bootstrap menu in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and using following sidemenu link as one of items as the app side menu,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="{{Request::is('vehicles*') ? 'active' : null}}"><a href="{{route('vehicles.myads')}}">My Ads</a></li>
      </ul>
 </nav>
```

and this sidemenu blade file is include with other blade files to show side menu, and above menu link route is following,

```
Route::get('myads', [
    'uses' => 'VehicleController@indexpersonel',
    'as'   => 'vehicles.myads',

]);
```

but when I visit myads blade file it is not highlight current menu items. how can fix this probelm?

**edit menu bar**

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
      {{dd(Request::path());}}
      <li class="{{ (Request::is('vehicles/*') || Request::is('vehicles') ? 'active' : '') }}"><a href="{{route('vehicles.myads')}}">My Ads</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: I assume that the Home tab is always active i.e. highlighted in case of others too. Is that correct?

Comment: ok I delete home tab, but still problem is here

Comment: remove semicolon from last

Comment: ok it is got **"myads"**

Comment: navigate to vehicles through url and check what is coming

Comment: please can you give me some example. I am new to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /,

```
<li class="{{Request::is('*/vehicles/*') ? 'active' : null}}">
```

For More details visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests

Is() method starts comparing URL from the first segment.

For Example:

1) Your URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/client/add and you want to check client is exists or not in URL so you need to do something like  `<li class="{{Request::is('*/client/*') ? 'active' : null}}">`

2) http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/client/add find an admin in URL or not

```
<li class="{{Request::is('admin/*') ? 'active' : null}}">
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: No, it is not success here

Comment: can you try with <li class="{{Request::is('myads') ? 'active' : null}}">?

Comment: did it but it is also not success here

Comment: try Request::segment(2) == 'myads'

Comment: I already did something link this, class=" {{ (Request::segment(2) == 'home' || Request::segment(2) == '' ) ? 'active show' : '' }} "

Comment: same thing here

Comment: answer is updated please check i'm sure it will work for you.

Comment: same thing here dude

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<li class="{{ (Request::is('myads/*') || Request::is('myads') ? 'active' : '') }}">
```

Comment: did it but it is also not success here

Comment: add dd(Request::path()); befor your route and show me the output

Comment: where should I put it can you give me some example please?

Comment: put it before top li tag

Comment: did you mean like this **dd(Request::path());
      <li class="{{ (Request::is('vehicles/*') || Request::is('vehicles') ? 'active' : '') }}"><a href="{{route('vehicles.myads')}}">My Ads</a></li>**

Comment: position is ok and  like this {{dd(Request::path()) }}

Comment: it is got ** (1/1) FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected ';'**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182915/discussion-between-banda-and-shaielndra-gupta).

Comment: No, dear it is same thing here

Comment: @banda according to my knowledge it should be worked for you

Comment: do `php artisan route:list` in terminal of you project root diractory and show me the route list